# Audio distortion when block streaming from a file (Octave)

Tags: matlab, audio, file-io, octave

---

I am setting up a simple audio IO system which simulates 'real-time block processing' by calling a block at a time from a file that is already stored in memory.

---

At the minute, I have a simple script which retreives the data from a file, and then enters a while loop which extracts one block at a time and provides a first order butterworth lowpass filter at 600 Hz (a skeleton setup to test). Each block is then processed and added onto another array which is declared outside the scope of the while loop, so that the processed data can be written to a wave file after completion.

---

To filter the data I am using the Octave *signal* pkg to generate the coefficients ([butter](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/butter.html)), and then the built in [filter](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/filter.html) function to apply the IIR filter.

**The problem is that if I apply no filter affect i.e. input = output the audio sounds the exact same. However, if I apply a filter every time a block is called, a ringing is created that digitally distorts the signal quite heavily.**

---

Please see the following script for the setup (it is only handling mono audio for the minute).

```
# Reset
close all; clear all;

# Audio file path
fileName = 'test.wav';

# Init routines
[x,fs] = audioread(fileName);
xlen = length(x);
[dim1,dim2] = size(x);
y = zeros(dim1,dim2);
[b,a] = butter(1, (600./(fs*0.5)));    
index = 1;
blockSize = 256;

# Enter process loop
while(index + blockSize < xlen)

  # Extract one block
  audioBlock(:,1) = x(index : index + blockSize - 1, 1);

  # Do process
  outAudioBlock = filter(b,a,audioBlock);

  # Store output block
  y(index : index + blockSize - 1, 1) = outAudioBlock(:);

  # Update index 
  index += blockSize;

endwhile

# Write to outputs
audiowrite('processed.wav', y, fs);
audiowrite('processed1.wav', filter(b,a,y), fs);
```

The second audiowrite is just an example which confirms filtering the whole audio data in one call creates no distortion, wheareas the block filtering creates noticeable digital distortion.

---

As a side note :

I have also attempted using different filtering techniques with frequency domain multiplication with windowing and then ifft back (with octaves fftfilt & using just the fft) as well as time domain convolution and creating an overlap add method. The same effect also occurs when applying an FIR filter rather than using IIR coefficients.

I am also aware that this example disregards the last block or so of audio but for this use case I am not bothered with the last block's zero padding.

---

I am not sure what I am missing; any ideas?

**EDIT 1: The idea was not to use frequency domain processing if possible (just the time domain IIR/FIR filtering), but I investigated the frequency domain multiplications to see if a similar distortion result occured (which it did).**

Comment: Im no expert but this seems like an discrete fft thing. You are getting bad frequencies and stuff that generate extra ugly sounds. Unfortunately my expertise ends in this vague sentence. I think you may be able to solve this by zero padding the blocks (to `nextpow2` size), and after the filter removing the extra values.

Comment: Its really strange I've created a similar thing in Matlab a long time ago now and never had any issues like this. And I thought it might be something like that so I tried the windowing with FFT filtering, but still not much different :/. It shouldn't have a DFT effect if using the normal time domain filtering function either (there is no fourier transform involved its just delays/gains).

Comment: All true indeed. Out of ideas

Comment: Try overlapped windowing

Comment: The idea was to not use frequency domain processing if possible; I just wasn't sure where the distortion was coming from so thought I'd see if it was still happening.

Comment: When you `filter` you are not using the frequency domain per se, but you are applying the maths of it, so you should still be careful. Ultimately you are using the maths of the [Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an edge effect thing. You apply a causal IIR filter to `audioBlock`. To compute the first sample, the state is initialized to all zeros. If I remember correctly, this is equivalent to assuming that the signal before the first sample is all zeros. This likely creates a discontinuity, which will affect a certain number of samples at the beginning of the block. Because you use an IIR filter, this effect could potentially carry on for a long time. Using a FIR filter is safer in that respect.

Let's assume `margin` samples are affected. You could amend your code as follows to extend your signal by that amount and prevent the distortion:

```
while(index + blockSize < xlen)

  % Extract one block
  if index==1
    audioBlock = x(index : index + blockSize - 1);
  else
    audioBlock = x(index - margin : index + blockSize - 1);
  end

  % Do process
  outAudioBlock = filter(b,a,audioBlock);

  % Store output block
  if index==1
    y(index : index + blockSize - 1) = outAudioBlock;
  else
    y(index : index + blockSize - 1) = outAudioBlock(margin+1:end);
  end

  % Update index 
  index += blockSize;

end
```

(Disclaimer: I don't have octave installed here, and my copy of MATLAB doesn't have the signal processing toolbox, so I cannot test the above code.)

---

**Unsolicited advice:**

- Your data is all 1D, use 1D (linear) indexing. It's more efficient, and shorter to type. (See my code above.)
- Don't do `audioBlock(:,1) =` when extracting a new bit of signal. Simply assign the result to the variable. It's *much* faster, and won't give problems if the signal size changes and you forget to reset the variable.
- Don't start with `close all; clear all;`. Instead, write `function <filename>` at the top of the script. This converts the script into a function, meaning it gets its own workspace. This is a much safer way of working, as you don't accidentally use existing variables in your script, and you don't accidentally erase anything in your base workspace.
- I used `end` instead of `endwhile`. This is the same, but also works on MATLAB. There is no reason not to use the most portable option.
- I used `%` instead of `#`. Again, the same but portable. Note how the SO syntax highlighting works with `%` but not `#`! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is IIR, which means it has a state that you need to preserve from frame to frame. The 'filter' function has state input and state output parameters for this very reason, but you're not using those in your code. That's why in every frame, the filter starts from a clean state, which is bound to create artifacts. The fix is easy: initialize a variable 'state' to [] before entering the loop, and add it to the input and output parameters in the call of the filter function like so:

[outAudioBlock, state] = filter(b,a,audioBlock,state);